# How to convert text to html?

Tags: php, html

i want to make thinks like to convert text into html

simple text would be like this

```
   "Vehicle Title Not Required/Not Issued 

•1962 and older year model vehicles 
•Agricultural, horticultural or livestock raising equipment or vehicles that are not required to be registered 
•Airplanes, aircraft 
•All terrain vehicles, off-road vehicles 
•Boat trailers 
•Boats, watercraft"
```

i want to convert it to this

```
<p><span>"Vehicle Title Not Required/Not Issued&nbsp;</span><br /><br /><span>&bull;1962 and older year model vehicles&nbsp;</span><br /><span>&bull;Agricultural, horticultural or livestock raising equipment or vehicles that are not required to be registered&nbsp;</span><br /><span>&bull;Airplanes, aircraft&nbsp;</span><br /><span>&bull;All terrain vehicles, off-road vehicles&nbsp;</span><br /><span>&bull;Boat trailers&nbsp;</span><br /><span>&bull;Boats, watercraft"&nbsp;</span></p>
```

how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to do anything yourself?

Answer (score 1):

I assume from the tag that you want to do this in PHP.

There are several PHP functions (like htmlencode and htmlentities) which do similar things.

I found this one to work consistently:

mb_convert_encoding(htmlspecialchars($string), 'HTML-ENTITIES')

Comment: Dear Sir,I try example in that document of php but nothing work<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>

Comment: Hi, you need to realize that a string is either in HTML format (e.g. &gt;) or it is not (>). The function(s) that I mentioned can be used to convert plain text to HTML.
When the string's value is HTML, you shouldn't encode it again (by using a function like htmlentities), because this double encoding will read the HTML as if it is plain text and therefore ruin it.

Comment: I am using the xampp+windows 8.1 .this code does not work on my setup but.http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c4a32bf99aa8fd6246c4a77132a023d32945363   here works fine what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

simple:

```
<?php
  $input = " ... your text from above ...";
  echo "<p><span>";
  echo str_replace("\n", "</span><br /><br /><span>", $input);
  echo "</span></p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list element instead.

```
<p><span>&quot;Vehicle Title Not Required/Not Issued</span><br>
<ul>
<li>1962 and older year model vehicles</li>
<li>Agricultural, horticultural or livestock raising equipment or vehicles that are not required to be registered</li>
<li>Airplanes, aircraft </li>
<li>All terrain vehicles, off-road vehicles </li>
<li>Boat trailers </li>
<li>Boats, watercraft&quot;</li>
</ul>
```

PHP Code(you might want use it) :

```
<?php
echo "
<p><span>&quot;Vehicle Title Not Required/Not Issued</span><br>
<ul>
<li>1962 and older year model vehicles</li>
<li>Agricultural, horticultural or livestock raising equipment or vehicles that are not required to be registered</li>
<li>Airplanes, aircraft </li>
<li>All terrain vehicles, off-road vehicles </li>
<li>Boat trailers </li>
<li>Boats, watercraft&quot;</li>
</ul>
";
?>
```